# how to make foreign key relationship on physically distributed data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, linked-server

- three servers
- server 1 is central point which links the other two servers.
- the other two servers have a table which has a field which should act like a foreign key

### problem

well i do not know how to do this, using vs08 or sql server 08

diagram view

table on server 1

> sv1pg1 id -- primary key
>   details

tables same schema on srvr2 and srvr3

> linkedSRVid -- pk
>   linkedto    -- fk  constrain should be between (server 1 primary key and this field)

note that

"this is just a simplest! way i can think of to represent the prob, the real dbs contain

many fields and tables and the following applies"

- it's not always that the network connection between the server remains up.
- the link only need for "writing purpose" not viewing, as viewing done by direct

connection to the respective server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key constraint can reference other tables only **[within the same database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx)**. This means that even if those databases were on the same server it still would not work.

Considering that the schemas are the same, you may want to look into **[replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)**.

Comment: thanks, you confirmed a point, but using replication is not possible, is there another work around?